# Identity in Blazor after reload page user are logout

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, identity

i have the problem after reload the blazor server page the user is no longer logged in

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;    
})
         .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()         
         .AddXpoIdentityStores<XpoApplicationUser, XpoApplicationRole>()         
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

how i can fix this problem

Comment: You have to upload much more detailed code. However, have you tried these methods?
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920836/identity-server-4-2-0-not-reading-asp-net-core-identity-cookies
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883059/reloading-page-affecting-sign-out-of-user-log-out